# xterm highlighting always white, not reverse

Tags: colors, xterm, i3, xdm

I'm running Debian on my desktop, laptop, and netbook. On my desktop and laptop, I am using Gnome desktop environment; whereas my netbook is using i3wm (installed after a text-only install initially). In all cases, I am using the base16 colour sets in the same way (sourced from .bashrc).
In both cases, the underlying `TERM` variable is `xterm-256color`. The netbook uses `xdm` while the others use `gdm`.

On my desktop and laptop, my highlighting works correctly, as seen here:
[image: Desktop Highlighting]

Note how the bar at the bottom of `man` reverses the colour of the text; and selecting the line in the terminal reverses the colour of the text also.

However, on the netbook, this is what I am getting:
[image: Netbook Highlighting]

Note how the highlighting is always white, regardless of what is underneath.

I have no idea why this is. I did something the other day which temporarily fixed it, but I do not remember what I did, nor if I undid it; and it is currently displaying as in the image.

Can anybody tell me how I can fix this? Where would the setting be for this highlighting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Selection* probably means with the mouse (or touchpad).  In [`xterm`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html), there are resource settings related to that:

> **`highlightColor`**
>   Specifies  the  color  to  use  for  the background of selected
>   (highlighted) text.   If  not  specified  (i.e.,  matching  the
>   default  foreground),  reverse  video  is used.
>
> **`highlightColorMode`**
>   Specifies whether xterm should use `highlightTextColor` and `highlightColor`  to override the reversed foreground/background colors in a selection.
>
> **`highlightReverse`**
>   Specifies whether xterm should reverse the selection foreground
>   and  background  colors  when selecting text with reverse-video
>   attribute.
>
> **`highlightTextColor`**
>   Specifies  the  color  to  use  for  the foreground of selected
>   (highlighted) text.   If  not  specified  (i.e.,  matching  the
>   default  background),  reverse  video  is used.

Perhaps you used something with `xrdb` to modify the settings.  Putting them in a resource file works well enough.

Comment: Thank You. I don't remember changing any of these values, but setting highlightReverse to on has fixed my problem.